# Add dollar sign to front of SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, object

I am pulling information from a MSSQL query using PHP and some of it is in integer form.

I have assigned the query results to an object class:

```
$dataEx->PartCost = $row[2]; 
$dataEx->VendorCost = $row[3];
```

Then assigned those to variables:

```
    $partCost = $dataEx->PartCost;
  $vendorCost = $dataEx->VendorCost;
```

I want to add the dollar sign ($) to the front of both of those variables before echoing them out.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Just escape `$` and you can print it... `echo "\$$partCost";`

Comment: `echo "$".$partCost;`

Comment: Could `echo` with `sprintf()` too.

Comment: Or maybe: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest using http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php to ensure they are formatted properly each time.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
$partCost = money_format('%.2n',$dataEx->PartCost);
$vendorCost = money_format('%.2n',$dataEx->VendorCost);
```

If you do not want to format it, simply concat the string:

```
$partCost = "$" . $dataEx->PartCost;
$vendorCost = "$" . $dataEx->VendorCost;
```

Or:

```
$partCost = chr(36) . $dataEx->PartCost;
$vendorCost = chr(36) . $dataEx->VendorCost;
```

See more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Hope that helps.